# Type Ahead Regex For String Of Numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, meteor

I am using [typeahead](https://github.com/sergeyt/meteor-typeahead) to perform a server side query to look up a phone number associated with a Meteor user. However I can't get the Regular Expression Correct.
What should my `RegExp` look like? The `phoneNumber` field should look like : `1234567890`, i.e 10 numbers.

```
   searchPhone: function(query, options) {
    options = options || {};

    // guard against client-side DOS: hard limit to 50
    if (options.limit) {
        options.limit = Math.min(50, Math.abs(options.limit));
    } else {
        options.limit = 50;
    }

    var regex = new RegExp("^" + query);
    return Meteor.users.find({'profile.phoneNumber': {$regex:  regex}}, options).fetch();
}
```

Comment: Why not just use https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/autocomplete, which typeahead copied this code from? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a regex that only allows digits `[0-9]` and exactly 10 of them: `{10}`

```
var regex = /([0-9]){10}/;
```

[RegExr](http://regexr.com/) is awesome for practicing your regex-fu.